# Let $A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be real symmetric matrices, prove that $AB=O$.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**

Let $A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be real symmetric matrices. Suppose that we have $\begin{pmatrix}A+B&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix}A&O\\O&B\end{pmatrix}$. Prove that $AB=O$.

**My attempt:**

As we know that real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, so the condition is equivalent to that $\sigma(A+B)\cup\{0\}^n=\sigma(A)\cup\sigma(B)$. Then $\text{tr}(A+B)^2=\text{tr}\ A^2+\text{tr}\ B^2$, i.e. $\text{tr}\ AB=0$.

Consider $A$ and $B$ as self-adjoint operators on Hilbert space $H=\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we have orthogonal decomposition $H=\ker (A+B)\oplus\text{im}(A+B)$. Note that $\text{rank}(A+B)=\text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(B)$, then we have $\text{im}(A+B)=\text{im}(A)\oplus\text{im}(B)$ and $\ker(A+B)=\ker A\cap\ker B$. Therefore $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint operators on $H'=\text{im}(A+B)$ and they vanish on $\ker(A+B)$. All in all, we can suppose that $A+B$ is invertible.

Now we have orthogonal decomposition $H=\ker A\oplus\text{im}\ A$ and $H=\ker B\oplus\text{im}\ B$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @MatrixBi Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/81360). Please [edit] your question to tell us where you encountered this problem, what you have tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts you have.

Comment: @MatrixBi For example, are you able to show that the result holds in the case that $A,B$ are positive semidefinite?

Comment: @MatrixBi How do you go from $\text{rank}(A+B)=\text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(B)$ to $\text{im}(A+B)=\text{im}(A)\oplus\text{im}(B)$?

Comment: $(A+B)v=Av+Bv$,  so $\text{im}(A+B)\subset\text{im}(A)+\text{im}(B)$.

Comment: I agree with you there. However, you seem to be saying that we have an orthogonal decomposition $\text{im}(A+B)=\text{im}(A)\oplus\text{im}(B)$. Note that this orthogonal decomposition is not implied from the rank equality alone; for example, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}.
$$

Comment: @MatrixBi Again, it would help if you could tell us where you encountered this question. For instance, if this is from a certain textbook, then there may be some relevant theorem that the creator of the question had in mind.

Comment: @MatrixBi Also, note that because $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, $AB = 0$ is equivalent to the statement that the subspaces ${\rm im}(A),{\rm im}(B)$ are orthogonal.

Comment: +1 for showing your efforts

Comment: To complete OP's approach: assume WLOG $\det(A+B)\neq 0$ so $\dim( \ker A + \ker B) = \dim \ker A + \dim \ker B = n$. Create orthogonal matrix from respective kernels $Q:=\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c} \mathbf Q_1 & \mathbf Q_2\end{array}\bigg]$.  $A Q= Q\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0 &\mathbf *\\ \mathbf 0 &\mathbf *\end{bmatrix}=Q\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0 &\mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0 &\mathbf *\end{bmatrix}$ where $A$ kills $\mathbf Q_1$ by design and $Q^TA Q$ is symmetric. Similarly $BQ=Q\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf * &\mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0 &\mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}$. Conclude $ABQ =Q\mathbf 0\implies AB=\mathbf 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ and $b=\operatorname{rank}(B)$. By a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that
$$
A=\pmatrix{\Lambda\\ & 0}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B=UDU^T=\pmatrix{U_1\\ U_2}D\pmatrix{U_1^T&U_2^T}
$$
where $\Lambda\in GL_a(\mathbb R)$ and $D\in GL_b(\mathbb R)$ are two nonsingular diagonal matrices, $U\in M_{n\times b}(\mathbb R)$ has orthonormal columns, $U_1$ is $a\times b$ and $U_2$ is $(n-a)\times b$. Then
$$
A+B=\underbrace{\pmatrix{I_a&U_1\\ 0&U_2}\pmatrix{\Lambda\\ &D}}_X\underbrace{\pmatrix{I_a&0\\ U_1^T&U_2^T}}_Y=XY.
$$
By Sylvester's secular theorem,
$$
YX=\pmatrix{I_a&0\\ U_1^T&U_2^T}\pmatrix{I_a&U_1\\ 0&U_2}\pmatrix{\Lambda\\ &D}
$$
has the same multi-set of nonzero eigenvalues as $XY=A+B$. However, $(A+B)\oplus0$ is similar to $A\oplus B$, which in turn is similar to $\Lambda\oplus D\oplus0$. Therefore, the nonzero eigenvalues of $YX$ are precisely the eigenvalues of the nonsingular diagonal matrix $\Lambda\oplus D$. Hence $YX$ and $\Lambda\oplus D$ have the same spectrum and also the same determinant. It follows that
$$
1=\det\left[\pmatrix{I_a&0\\ U_1^T&U_2^T}\pmatrix{I_a&U_1\\ 0&U_2}\right]
=\det\pmatrix{I_a&U_1\\ U_1^T&I_b}=\det(I_b-U_1^TU_1).
$$
As $U$ has orthonormal columns, $I_b\succeq U_1^TU_1\succeq0$. Therefore $\det(I_b-U_1^TU_1)=1$ implies that $U_1=0$. Consequently,
$$
A=\pmatrix{\Lambda\\ &0}, \quad B=\pmatrix{0\\ &U_2DU_2^T}
$$
and $AB=0$.